# Change EJB project to web app

Tags: eclipse, spring, ejb

I've created a Java EE project in Eclipse. But now I've decided to use Spring instead, so I want it to be a simpler dynamic web application. I think that means I must remove the "EJB Module" project facet and add the "Dynamic Web Module" facet. But Eclipse refuses to let me do so, complaining that "EJB 3.1 module can not be uninstalled". I can't believe Eclipse makes my intention impossible, so how do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to remove the Java EE facets by manually editing the `.project` file, changing the natures to remove the Java EE natures:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui.wikiTextNature</nature>
</natures>
```